# Writing jQuery more eloquenty - combining logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrolltop

I have written a simple script which works fine.

```
var mywindow = $(window);
var mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
var up = false;
var uiscroll;
mywindow.scroll(function () {
uiscroll = mywindow.scrollTop();
if (uiscroll > mypos && !up) {

$('div').addClass('down');
    up = !up;
    console.log(up);
} else if(uiscroll < mypos && up) {

$('div').removeClass('down');
    up = !up;
}
mypos = uiscroll;

 if (mywindow.scrollTop() > 200) { 
  $('div').addClass('test');
}
else {
   $('div').removeClass('test');
}

});
```

The script applies three different css states to a div depending on three different conditions of the scroll. up or down & how far the scroll is away from the top.

What's bugging me is that there has to be better, more eloquent way of writing this than what I've hacked together.  I just can't quite wrap my head around it though.

Just trying to learn to write scripts better so that what I put together isn't so laughable.  I learn best by looking at examples.

Appreciate any help/guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt

```
var mypos = 0;
var up = false;
var $div = $('div');
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var uiscroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (uiscroll > mypos && !up) {
        $div.addClass('down');
        up = !up;
    } else if(uiscroll < mypos && up) {
        $div.removeClass('down');
        up = !up;
    }
    mypos = uiscroll;
    $div.toggleClass('test',uiscroll>200);
});
```

I removed the `mywindow` var because it's not necessary. `mypos` can be initialized with 0.

You can reference the window inside the scroll handler with `$(this)`.

Instead of telling jQuery to find `div` multiple times, tell it to find it once and store it in a jquery object. It is actually quite expensive/wasteful to search for the same element multiple times, especially in a scroll event which is fired many times. If you need to reference the same element multiple times, it's always better to store it in a variable.

`toggleClass('classname',boolean)`

is just short hand for

```
if(boolean is true)
    //add class
else
    //remove class
```

jsFiddle so you can test it

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/Ldp5b92s/

Comment: Thanks.  Looks much more concise.  

It has only one problem.  When I read your code, I think it should work but it doesn't. :D

Comment: Hehe.. yeah shorter code doesn't always mean it's better. I tested it in a jsFiddle before i posted just to make sure i wasn't breaking anything. Also my code assumes document is ready.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to just ask you that very same question.  Whenever I see a code that does not fire nor error, I just add document .ready to see if that fixes it.

And adding document.ready to your code makes it work.  

I never understood precisely when document.ready is needed.  I know that js cannot fire before the html element is drawn.  But I really don't understand this part. 

"my code assumes document is ready" - how can I know this without testing your code?

Comment: By the way, thank you for providing explanations along with your code.  Your explanation is just as helpful as the code sample.

Comment: Javascript can execute before any html is drawn, it's just that if the js tries to access the DOM before it's ready, then it will fail. So you can do other stuff like math, ajax requests, app initialization before doc is ready, because that code doesn't involve the DOM. Generally, any time you see the jquery object `$`, you should assume the code takes place inside a document ready. Because it just doesn't make sense to use jQuery DOM functions when the document is not ready. Happy to help.

Comment: Eric, thank you so much for your "tutorial."  haha

Your replies are 10X more helpful that some tutorials that are out there.

Thanks!!! You rock!!!!